# Having trouble working out what is wrong with this code

Tags: python

Here is part of my code, I keep getting error message saying

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\python1\python1.py", line 14, in 
    A = int(gtin8code[0])*3
TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '**getitem**'
Can anyone tell me what is wrong?

```
gtin8code = int(input("Please enter your gtin-8 barcode"))
A = int(gtin8code[0])*3
B = int(gtin8code[1])
C = int(gtin8code[2])*3
D = int(gtin8code[3])
E = int(gtin8code[4])*3
F = int(gtin8code[5])
G = int(gtin8code[6])*3
total = (A+B+C+D+E+F+G)
  #print(total)
```

I am a beginner so plz don't be rude.

Comment: Well the error is clear isn't it: `gtin8code` already is an `int`. So you cannot obtain `gtin8code[0]`...

Comment: Int types don't have `__getitem__`. Change the cast on the first line to `str`

Answer (score 2):

You need to input the barcode as a string, since you're then treating every character as an `int` individually:

```
gtin8code = input("Please enter your gtin-8 barcode")
```

Comment: so what do I change?

Comment: @ScopoPhobia you remove the `int` cal on the `input` line.

Comment: @ScopoPhobia really? it works for me... unless you are using Python 2.x then you would have to use `raw_input()` instead.

Comment: ye I think that is the problem because it works on python 3 but not python 2.7.11. thanks